# How can i convert this Do While loop into another sort of loop, a while loop?

Tags: java, loops, methods, while-loop, do-while

```
public void humanPlay()
 {
if (player1.equalsIgnoreCase("human"))
    System.out.println("It is player 1's turn.");
else
    System.out.println("It is player 2's turn.");

System.out.println("Player 1 score: " + player1Score);
System.out.print("Player 2 score: " + player2Score);

String eitherOr;

  do {
    eitherOr= input.nextLine(); 
    humanRoll();
  } while (eitherOr.isEmpty());

 if (!eitherOr.isEmpty())
    humanHold();

}
```

This is the whole method, The only thing i am trying to fix is this.

```
       String eitherOr;
do {
     eitherOr= input.nextLine();    
     humanRoll();
   } while (eitherOr.isEmpty());
```

It has to accept input multiple times, so each time input is needed to determine what happens, which is why i like the Do While loop, but since it initializes at least once per time, i get an extra roll than needed.

I have tried to do it this way, and various variations of this way:

```
String eitherOr = input.nextLine();

while(eitherOr.isEmpty());
        humanRoll();
```

This does not work because it does not ask for the input over again. If i try to put the input.nextline(); into the while loop, it says "eitherOr" is not initialized, and even if i initialize it  when i enter input, the command line stays blank, so it does nothing with my input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got an extraneous semi-colon:

```
while(eitherOr.isEmpty());
    humanRoll();'
```

should be:

```
while(eitherOr.isEmpty())
    humanRoll();
```

Essentially your version is saying to do nothing while `eitherOr.isEmpty()` is `true` and so it never gets to call `humanRoll`.

Comment: Well then, it seems like the last hour has been wasted on a semi colon. Thank you, I have not used a while-loop in a while. Due to this misfortune I foresee me re-reading a few chapters. Probably should have been the first thing i checked to be honest.

Comment: @ LanceySnr The code still works like it did while it was a do while loop, even if there is input, it still creates another roll.

Comment: Have you used a debugger or similar to check the content of it when there is input? Given the code posted I can't see how it could execute the loop.

Answer (score 1):

If your second code snippet you are executing a blank statement as part of your while loop

```
while(eitherOr.isEmpty());//this semicolon is a blank statement
    humanRoll();
```

you have to remove this semicolon in order to execute humanRoll as part of loop

```
while(eitherOr.isEmpty())
    humanRoll();
```

On a side note use of paranthesis generally avoids such minor issue

```
while(eitherOr.isEmpty()) {
    humanRoll();
}
```

In above code its easy to identify if an unintentional semicolon has been introduced or not.